# Error on Quoted Data fetch from Database

Tags: c#

i have question that when i fetch data from database and if in the databse have some quoted dat e.g. D`DUN. this data is inserted in DB. when i execute select query like :

```
  Select city from glmast where glname='" + list_customer.Items[i].Value + "'
```

in list_cutomer  there is data in which some data are inserted like D`DUN like quotes. so it gives error like unclosed Quotation.

so, how this will be solved because not all field contain Quotes.

Please Help Me..
Mitesh

Comment: what i replace please can you tell me more

Comment: what can i write instead of glname='" + list_customer.Items[i].Value + "'

Comment: @MiteshMachhi, see my answer what to replace.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use string concatenations when building SQL queries. You should use parametrized queries. Not only that your code will break in situations as the one you have described, but even worse, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and if your application falls in the hands of malicious users, your database will get busted.

So parametrized queries:

```
string sql = "SELECT city FROM glmast WHERE glname = @glname";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Some connection string"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@glname", list_customer.Items[i].Value);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do something with the results
        }
    }
}
```